# How to check if PowerShell result contains these words

Tags: powershell, windows-11, powershell-7.2

I'm doing an IF statement in PowerShell and at some point I do this:

```
(Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype
```

which gives me the results in this format, on top of each other

[image]

I want to write my IF statement to check whether the output of the command above contains both "TpmPin" and "RecoveryPassword" but not sure what the correct syntax is.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work as expected, the result is always true even if it should be false.

```
if ((Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype -contains "tpmpin" && "RecoveryPassword")
```

this doesn't work either:

```
if ((Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype -contains "tpmpinRecoveryPassword")
```

p.s I don't want to do nested IF statements because I'm already doing multiple of them.

Comment: What is `(Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype.GetType()`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it's `System.Array`

Comment: Wrong guesses..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the call to `Get-BitLockerVolume` before the `if` statement, store the result in a variable, then use the `-and` operator to ensure both are found:

```
$KeyProtectors = Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" |ForEach-Object KeyProtector
if($KeyProtectors.KeyProtectorType -contains 'TpmPin' -and $KeyProtectors.KeyProtectorType -contains 'RecoveryPassword'){
    # ... both types were present
}
```

---

If you have an arbitrary number of values you want to test the presence of, another way to approach this is to test that *none* of them are *absent*:

```
$KeyProtectors = Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:" |ForEach-Object KeyProtector

$mustBePresent = @('TpmPin', 'RecoveryPassword')

if($mustBePresent.Where({$KeyProtectors.KeyProtectorType -notcontains $_}, 'First').Count -eq 0){
    # ... all types were present
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that taught me a lot, is it also possible to convert that system array into some other type to query its content?

Comment: @zerogainer I don't understand the question. The `-contains` operator already works with the array?

Comment: Ah yes you're right, nevermind :)

Answer (score 1):

you can write a powershell if check like given below:

```
if((((Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype) -join ",")  -eq "Tpm,RecoveryPassword") 
{ 
      write-host "matches" 
} 
else 
{
      write-host "does not match"
}
```

> matches

**Caveat**: As told by @MathiasR.Jessen, this solution assumes the order of the values. So, if the values order changes, above solution will not work. We need to follow the solution provided by  @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: This is predicated on the order always being the same, I don't think that's a given.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, sorry. I agree with you. I have updated the answer with caveat